# Maven assembly plugin - flat unpack

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

If I have an archive that I want to unpack, is there a way to unpack it flat (files only, without dirs)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no way to do that. There is an [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-45) that left open since 05, no chance that someday it'll be fixed.